# MAPA function type = 'es' Error in !silent : invalid argument type

Tags: r, forecasting, forecast

```
mapa Multiple Aggregation Prediction Algorithm (Wrapper)
```

I want to use the mapa function in the MAPA package, everything works, and I mean everything, it does produces forecasts if I leave type empty.
But using:

```
 type = 'es'
```

Produces an error, I don't know why since the documentation says that:
<<*type* What type of exponential smoothing implementation to use. "es" = use from the smooth package; "ets" = use from the forecast package. Default is "es" >>
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MAPA/MAPA.pdf

Using type = 'ets' works fine, or just dont adding that parameter. I wanted to use xreg, but can't since it forces type type = 'es', thus producing the error.

```
> mapa(ts(c(1:80), frequency = 1), type = 'ets', outplot = 1)
MAPA fit MSE: 0.02, MAE: 0.13
Out-of-samplpe forecasts:
[1] 81.125
```

This is the error

```
> mapa(ts(c(1:80), frequency = 1), type = 'es', outplot = 1)
Error in !silent : invalid argument type
```

I have already re installed both MAPA and smooth packages.

```
devtools::install_github("config-i1/smooth")
```

```
devtools::install_github("trnnick/mapa")
```

Comment: Unfortunately I think this is a bug in `MAPA`. The only workarounds are: (1) `mapa` fixes the internal use of `silent="all"` to `silent=TRUE`; or (2) you copy the source for that function fixing the errant `es(...,silent="all")` call, perhaps having to `:::`-call internal functions as well. The second option is your more immediate option, but will require a bit more play to work around function calls from functions not exported from `MAPA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug.

`mapa::mapa` calls

```r
      # Turn off warnings for es - this is done when the model reduces pool 
      # due to sample size.
      fittemp <- suppressWarnings(es(ats,model=mapa.model,silent="all",xreg=xregA, ...))
```

(https://github.com/trnnick/mapa/blob/master/R/mapa.estim.R#L304)

So far fine, but if we look at `smooth/R/es.R`, we see that the function declaration is

```r
es_old <- function(y, model="ZZZ", persistence=NULL, phi=NULL,
               initial=c("optimal","backcasting"), initialSeason=NULL, ic=c("AICc","AIC","BIC","BICc"),
               loss=c("likelihood","MSE","MAE","HAM","MSEh","TMSE","GTMSE","MSCE"),
               h=10, holdout=FALSE, cumulative=FALSE,
               interval=c("none","parametric","likelihood","semiparametric","nonparametric"), level=0.95,
               bounds=c("usual","admissible","none"),
               silent=c("all","graph","legend","output","none"),
               xreg=NULL, regressors=c("use","select"), initialX=NULL, ...){
```

Notice that it is actually `es_old`? In commit [2d28169](https://github.com/config-i1/smooth/commit/2d28169c74dc988bf9b7c0e19ca3dd50d26be229), the message reads

> *New es() function, based on adam(). The old one is kept under the name of es_old()*

If we look for the new "real" `es()` function declaration, we find it in `smooth/R/es-adam.R`, and notice that `silent=` has changed from the string option of above to class `logical`.

```r
es <- function(y, model="ZZZ", lags=c(frequency(y)), persistence=NULL, phi=NULL,
               initial=c("optimal","backcasting","complete"), initialSeason=NULL, ic=c("AICc","AIC","BIC","BICc"),
               loss=c("likelihood","MSE","MAE","HAM","MSEh","TMSE","GTMSE","MSCE"),
               h=10, holdout=FALSE,
               # cumulative=FALSE,
               # interval=c("none","parametric","likelihood","semiparametric","nonparametric"), level=0.95,
               bounds=c("usual","admissible","none"),
               silent=TRUE,
               xreg=NULL, regressors=c("use","select"), initialX=NULL, ...){
```

(https://github.com/config-i1/smooth/blob/master/R/adam-es.R#L232)

Looking around `smooth` some more it is using `silent` as is if were logical (e.g., https://github.com/config-i1/smooth/blob/master/R/es.R#L700), so it appears that that package is consistent internally.

So it appears that the bug is solely in `MAPA` in that they have not adapted to the new argument syntax. (Though part of me wants to throw some blame on `smooth` for changing a not-obscure argument from `character` to `logical` ... I can imagine other ways to more gracefully deal with such a large change in the API. If I were maintaining `MAPA`, I'd add some logic so that revdep-tests at CRAN would have caught this problem.)